# Wavesurfer pause() issue

Tags: javascript, php

I'm an amateur coder and I'm trying to get something to work but I'm a little stuck.
Hope anyone can help me out.

For starters I'm using [wavesurfer](https://wavesurfer-js.org) to play audio which works fine.
I'm having multiple instances of wavesurfer initiated and they all play fine except for one hickup.
when I play audio from instance 2 while instance 1 is playing, it's audio overlaps and I don't know how I can pause instance 1.

I tried several things but ended up with nothing or broke wavesurfer.

This is how I'm currently initiating wavesurfer:

```
    //getplayer
function getplayer(location)
{
    var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: '#waveform',
        waveColor: 'white',
        progressColor: 'cyan',
    });

    if (wavesurfer.isPlaying())
    {

        wavesurfer.pause();
        wavesurfer.load(location);
        wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {

            wavesurfer.play();

        });

    }

    else {

        wavesurfer.load(location);
        wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {

            wavesurfer.play();

        });
    }
}
```

To pass the location to the function, I'm using ajax:

```
            <script>
            $(function() {
                  $('.playsong-".$i."').click(function(event) {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      $.ajax({
                          type: 'GET',
                          url: 'includes/ajax.php',
                          dataType :'html',
                          data : {songname : '" . $psong['sname'] . "', songpath : '" . $psong['sl'] . "'},
                          success :  function(data){

                              $('#waveform').html(data);

                          }
                      })
                 });
             }); 
        </script>
```

which is then passed to the ajax.php file and initiates the javascript:

```
<script>getplayer("<?= $location ?>")</script>
```

I believe that each time I'm calling the wavesurfer, I'm initiating a new instance of the player but I could be wrong...

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

after I had an epiphany, it seems that I was going at it, completely wrong.

I was indeed calling up several instances of the entire player instead of just passing the information to the player.

What I did was remove the ajax call completely.

then I added a onclick handler on the song buttons like this:

```
   public function profilesongview($currentuser) {

    $this->getmusic($currentuser);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($this->musicarray as $psong) {
        echo "<div class='col-md-12'>
            <a href='#' class='playsong-" . $i . "' onclick=getplayer('".$psong['sl']."')><div class='profile_song'>
            " . $psong['sname'] . "
            </div></a></div>";

        $i++;
    }

}
```

then I added the player's instance to a static part of the site et voila, all done!